# Ubuntu Core/Debian Compiling for MT2712

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, embedded, cross-compilation, arm64

I want to build latest kernel of Ubuntu core or Debian for MT2712 but I cannot find any ways to compile the Debian or Ubuntu for this.
Is MT2712 supported by Ubuntu or Debian?
Can anyone guide me about the process or point towards the link where I can get help for compiling Ubuntu core or Debian for MT2712.

#### Update

I've compiled the linux kernel for it using the instructions for arm64 versions but don't know how to flash this image into the device as it only runs on adb commands and goes into the bootloader when I run
`adb reboot bootloader`